# What does instance refer to in solidity/JavaScript

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

`DToken.deployed().then(function(instance){ token = instance; })`

This code I saw in truffle test. Can someone please tell what does this "instance" parameter refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A truffle-contract object, which represents the `DToken` contract deployed on the network.

This object exposes all the `public` and `external` functions of the `DToken` contract.